# How to use $Orderby in news MongoDB-C

Tags: mongodb, bson, mongodb-c

I can get my query results but I can not manage to retrieve them in ascending (or descending) order according to the value of my field "X" (int32). Could you help me?

Note that I use the latest version of MongoDB-C and in the old version I could very well use "$orderby" for my queries but in new version this function "bson_append_start_object()" dont exist.

Here's the structure part of my collection :

```
   by: [
      {
         id: ObjectId("XX"),
         type: NumberInt(1)
      } 
   ],
   timestamp: NumberInt()
```

and part of my code :

```
   bson_init(&array);
   bson_append_oid(&array, "id", 2, &oid);
   bson_append_int32(&array, "type", 4, 1);
   bson_init(&query);
   bson_append_document(&query, "by", 2, &array);
```

Thank you in advance.

Best regards.

Comment: I suggest you show some code.

Comment: You should still be able to use `$orderby` in the new C driver. From one of [the examples](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-c-driver/blob/master/examples/example-gridfs.c#L67) in the github repo the equivalent to `bson_append_start_object()` appears to be: `bson_append_document_begin (&query, "$orderby", -1, &child);`

Comment: bson_append_document_begin (&query, "$orderby", -1, &child); with bson_append_document_begin(&query, "$query", -1, &child); is the solution ! thanks

Comment: Thanks .. I was able to confirm it with one of the C driver devs, too :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can still use `$orderby` in the new C MongooDB driver.

Instead of `bson_append_start_object()`, the new API uses `bson_append_document_begin()`.

Sample usage from the [GridFS example in the github repo](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-c-driver/blob/master/examples/example-gridfs.c#L67):

```
  bson_init (&query);
  bson_append_document_begin (&query, "$orderby", -1, &child);
  bson_append_int32 (&child, "filename", -1, 1);
  bson_append_document_end (&query, &child);
  bson_append_document_begin (&query, "$query", -1, &child);
  bson_append_document_end (&query, &child);
```

Comment: Thanks, but now you can find a new question related to this post here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21332895/complex-query-with-two-orderby