# Complex query with two $OrderBy

Tags: mongodb, bson, mongodb-c

Here's the structure part of my collection :

```
by: [
   {
      id: ObjectId("XX"),
      type: NumberInt(1)
   } 
],
timestamp: NumberInt(), // is timestamp 1
status: NumberInt(0),
mails: [
   {
      id: ObjectId("YY"),
      text: "",
      timestamp: NumberInt(), // is timestamp 2
   }
]
```

I can recover my data in chronological order according to the timestamp 1 via the following lines:

```
...
bson_init(&query);
bson_append_document_begin(&query, "$orderby", -1, &child);
bson_append_int32(&child, "timestamp", -1, 1);
bson_append_document_end(&query, &child);
bson_append_document_begin(&query, "$query", -1, &child);
bson_append_document_end(&query, &child);
collection = mongoc_client_get_collection(client, "db", "prefix");
cursor = mongoc_collection_find(collection, MONGOC_QUERY_NONE, 0, 0, 0, &query, NULL, NULL);
while(mongoc_cursor_next(cursor, &doc)){
   bson_iter_t iter;
   if(bson_iter_init_find(&iter, doc, "status")){
      status = bson_iter_int32(&iter);
   }
   ...
}
...
```

But now I would like to retrieve all values in the array "mails" in chronological order (or not) ... Have you an idea of the procedure?

Comment: BTW, looks like you are sorting by `filename` key in your code. And you don't have this key in you example documents.

Comment: sorry its my fault. this is timestamp key, not filename

Comment: It's OK. BTW, check out my answer, maybe it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have to use [Aggregation Framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/) to get this working.

The idea (in javascript):

```
db.test.aggregate([
    { $unwind: "$mails" }, 
    { $sort: { timestamp: 1, "mails.timestamp": 1 } }, 
    { $group: { _id: "$_id", mails: { $push: "$mails" } } }
]);
```

I am not sure how to translate it to C at the moment. Try to check out [mongoc_collection_aggregate](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-c-driver/blob/master/doc/mongoc_collection_aggregate.txt) docs.